# Images showing in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari

Tags: html, css, image, safari

This string of code is working in other browsers but not safari.
I have tried many added strings of javascript but nothing seems to work. the site is [www.wthn.com](https://www.wthn.com)

please help.

thank you

```
<div class="product-featured-images js-sticky"> 

    <img class="js-featured-image featured-image active" src="https://cdn.accentuate.io/1998318305337/5012029440057/Fully%20Charged%20(HP).jpg?1856x2193" data-section="how-to-use"> 

    <img class="js-featured-image featured-image" src="https://cdn.accentuate.io/1998318305337/5012025999417/Fully%20Charged%20(Compressed).png?683x1024" data-section="benefits"> 

    <img class="js-featured-image featured-image" src="https://cdn.accentuate.io/1998318305337/5012026032185/Fully%20Charged.jpg?1080x1080" data-section="ingredients"> 

</div>
```

the main css on the images is:

```
.product-featured-images {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1; }

.product-featured-images.is-sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0; }

.product-featured-images.is-stuck-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 0; }

.featured-image {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  object-fit: cover; }

.featured-image.active {
  opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: The problem is you're setting `content: '';` on the `.featured-image` element. In Safari, this removes the image content. Browsers do not all render CSS the same, unfortunately.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that line of CSS?

Comment: @benjarwar That fixed it! Thank you for your help, been trying to fix this for days, someone else developed it and this was an oversight before we made these pages live. 

Thank you again!